# Is alloc+initWithString: same as copy?

Tags: cocoa, nsstring

Basically, the question is - are the following essentially the same?

```
NSString *value1 = ...;
NSString *value2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:value1];
```

and

```
NSString *value1 = ...;
NSString *value2 = [value1 copy];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Conceptually, yes. However, there is one difference: `alloc` always creates a new string, whereas `copy` may return the same string.

In particular, immutable objects, such as immutable strings, are likely respond to `copy` by returning themselves rather than creating and returning a copy. (After all, if you can't change anything about the original, why would you really need a copy?) Mutable strings will respond to it by creating and returning a copy, as you'd expect.

`initWithString:` is in the middle: It may release the receiver and return the string you gave it, similar to how `copy` may return the receiver. However, if that happens, it means you wasted the creation of the string you created with `alloc`. With `copy`, you may not need to create any additional objects at all.

About the only reason to use `alloc` and `initWithString:` is if you have your own subclass of NSString and want to make an instance of it from an existing string. `copy` won't use your desired subclass. Since subclassing NSString is practically never warranted in Cocoa, the same is true of using `initWithString:` (or `stringWithString:`).

So the bottom line is, just use `copy` (or `mutableCopy`). It's shorter, clearer about your intent, and can be faster.

Answer (score 0):

Non-mutable strings are treated a bit special, compared to ordinary objects, so in this case, yes, the two operations are the same.

To wit:

```
NSString *str1 = @"string";
NSString *str2 = [str1 copy];
NSString *str3 = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: str1];

NSLog(@"str1: %p, str2: %p, str3: %p", str1, str2, str3);
```

Which gives me the following output:

```
str1: 0x108a960b0, str2: 0x108a960b0, str3: 0x108a960b0
```

Since the pointer addresses are the same, we are talking about the same object.

Comment: You should always use `%p` for pointers. Don't assume that any integral type will be the same size as, or the correct representation of, a pointer.

Comment: Actually just saw this in the docs ( http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265 ): "%p adds 0x to the beginning of the output. If you don't want that, use %lx and cast to long." Not that it matters, but Apple does not seem to be too bothered about using %lx (with a proper cast, of course)+